How to parameterize the Prometheus rule for a small subset of instances?
I need to create a rule for Prometheus that compares the value of some metric to a threshold value. The threshold value is the same for most of instances, but differs for two or three. Is there an easy and reliable way to parameterize a rule?
May be something like this:
- alert: HighValueAlert
  expr: my_metric > my_metric_threshold
  for: 5m

Where my_metric_threshold is an "artificial" metric which is defined somewhere e.g. using Node exporter textfile collector (or perhaps using another method that I have no idea about):
my_metric_threshold{instance="special1"} 101
my_metric_threshold{instance="special2"} 102
my_metric_threshold 100  # default for most of instances

Wishes for reliability:

If I forgot to specify a special threshold value for some instance, it should be processed with the default threshold value.
If a metric with a default threshold value is missing too (for example, I accidentally deleted .prom file), I should receive some kind of alert about the incorrect configuration (perhaps using a separate rule).

I'm new to Prometheus and I couldn't find any examples of solving this problem.
I'm setting up indoor temperature monitoring rules. The upper temperature threshold for most rooms is the same, but for 2-3 rooms it needs to be increased. Otherwise we will get too frequent alerts. The same applies to the lower temperature threshold.

Your general approach is correct. But here are a couple suggestions how to make your life easier.

Make names of special thresholds different from default one.

my_metric_threshold_special{instance="server1"} 101
my_metric_threshold_special{instance="server42"} 102
my_metric_threshold_default 100  
# if you'll expose it through textfile collector too, it will also have an instance label.
# It doesn't matter, just make sure to expose it only once.


Separate alert rules for default case and special cases

- alert: HighValueAlertDefault
  expr: my_metric > on() group_left() my_metric_threshold_default unless on(instance) my_metric_threshold_special
- alert: HighValueAlertSpecial
  expr: my_metric > on(instance) group_left() my_metric_threshold_special

Here default alert rule compares ignoring all labels, and disregards metrics of instances that have special thresholds.
And special alert rule simply compares metric to threshold.

To check my_metric_threshold_default you can use expression
absent(my_metric_threshold_default) or count(my_metric_threshold_default)>1


Thanks for the answer! I'll try to figure out your solution (I don't yet fully understand the effect of the group_left, on, unless operators). It's a bit of a surprise that I need to fork every rule that I would like to parameterize in this way. I'll keep the question open for a few days in hopes that someone has other thoughts to share. I've also added a little more detail to the question about exactly what problem I'm solving.

@keV, I recommend reading the documentation; I believe it provides good explanation about operators you mentioned. And regarding two rules, in theory you can do everything in a single rule, but it will be cumbersome. You wouldn't getaway with simple comparison, like in your question, because labels are different in default and special cases, and will need a separate handling.
